# Limit Core Data Entities Shown In UITableView row

Tags: core-data, uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I think I'm just missing something obvious here, but it's one of those frustrating things that's somehow eluding me.

I have a Core Data Entity called ProjectEntry. The ProjectEntry objects are displayed in uitableviews, using various attributes, arranged by date (attributes include things like "dateAsNSDate"[NSDate], "month"[NSString], "year"[NSString], "dayOfWeek"[NSString]).

I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController to populate the table views.

When I initially create and save the ProjectEntry object, the "dateAsNSDate" attribute is parsed and converted into various NSStrings. One string, also an attribute, is called "concatMonthAndYear". It takes the "month" and "year" strings and just joins them. So I get things such as "January 2014", "February 2015", etc.

I use the "concatMonthAndYear" as my cell.textLabel.text string to display in my tableview cells.

I use the NSDate attribute to sort the tableview rows (sortDescriptor), and the "year" attribute as my section headers (sectionNameKeyPath).

So right now, I'd have a tableview section called "2014", with tableview rows each representing a Core Data object, named things like "January 2014", February 2014", etc, in said section.

I can tap on one of those rows, segue to another tableview, and list all objects created in January 2014, for example, by using an NSPredicate on the second tableview.

However, on my first tableview, each Core Data object created is represented by its own tableview row. So I'll get multiple rows reading "January 2014" or "May 2015" or whatever. They're valid saved objects, and I want them, but I'd like to prevent a new row from being created if that "concatMonthAndYear" already exists. If a row titled "January 2014" already exists, I don't want a new row created. I want the new Core Data object stored, just not a new tableviewrow representing it. I only need one row with "January 2014", for example, to segue into a table listing ALL the entities from January 2014.

I know how to use an NSPredicate to get ALL the January 2014 objects into the second table, but how do I get JUST ONE object into the first table?

Is NSPredicate not the right device for that? Should I be somehow preventing a new cell from being created in the UITableView delegate methods? Each tableview row should be unique, and I'm stuck on whether it should be handled with the NSFetchedResults controller or in the tableview delegate methods?

Or some other way?

Can someone point in the right direction?

[image: Table 1]
[image: Table 2]

EDITED TO INCLUDE CODE:

```m
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    // 1 - Decide which Entity
    NSString *entityName = @"ProjectEntry";
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    // 2 - Request Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"monthYearTableSecHeader", @"year"]];

    // 3 - Filter it
    //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" "];

    // 4 - Sort it
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"year"
                                                                                                 ascending:NO],
                                                         [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateAsNSDate"
                                                                                                                                             ascending:YES
                                                                                       selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)], nil];


    //5 - Fetch
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"year"
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

    [self performFetch];

}
```

Comment: Have you considered filtering using a KVC collection operator such as ``distinctUnionOfObjects`` ?

Comment: No. To be honest, I wasn't aware of such a thing until your comment. I began reading up on it, but am unsure how to apply it to the predicate in the above code. Again, I'm probably missing the obvious...

Comment: If you set propertiesToGroupBy, you can also use a havingPredicate to do a post-fetch filter. Again, this only applies if you are using the ``NSDictionaryResultType``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```m
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"concatMonthAndYear", @"year"]];
```

This will cause the fetch request to return distinct dictionary objects corresponding to "January 2014", etc. objects.

**However**, you cannot use a fetch request controller's delegate methods (to hear of updates to the data).

If you need to hear updates, I suggest you add a layer of indirection to your data, where `MonthEntry` is an object representing yearly months and have a one to many relationship with `ProjectEntry`, which is your normal entity. This way, you can set the fetch request entity to `MonthEntry`.

Comment: That looks interesting. I'm going to test that out. I'll mark it "solved" ASAP.

Comment: I've edited the initial question to include the setting of the fetchedResultsController. Using that method, which I'm pretty sure is returning whole managed objects, there's nowhere I can include similar code to your suggestion, correct? I'd have to go with your suggestion to create a separate Entity? Also note that the "performFetch" method at the end is included in a subclass of UITableViewController that Paul Hegarty of Stanford suggests in his lectures. I'm using that for now, until I can get most of the other parts working.

Comment: My suggested code can be added in the construction of the fetch request.

Comment: see above edit, when included in constructing the request, I get this error: terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSFetchedResultsController does not support both change tracking and fetch request's with NSDictionaryResultType'

Comment: Does the problem come from the fetch request being constructed to return a whole managed object rather than a dictionary object made from specific attributes on that Entity? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding it here? I realize I'm probably not knowledgable enough yet to fully grasp it yet....                     would i need to modify the fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName method to request something OTHER than a "full" object (for lack of a better term)?

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you set the delegate of the fetch results controller, you cannot use dictionary return type. If you need to track changes, you will need to use a different entity.

Comment: Right. You've pointed me the the correct direction. I very much appreciate it, and am going to modify the project to include that second Entity.

Comment: That is the better option. Remember, when you create new `ProjectEntry ` objects, you have to connect them to the object of the new type (or create one and then connect).